# android background service catch events from gps navigation application

Tags: android, google-maps, events, android-intent, service

I'm currently wondering whether it's possible for a service running in background to catch events from Google map application or another gps navigation app such as destination_reached or trip_started. 
The goal would be to prompt a dialog on those events to ask the user whether he would like to retain informations about a trip in another application.